"Have the guts" vs "Be Brave". Does "have the guts" always imply determination?
According to CD:

guts means bravery and determination OR courage in dealing with danger or uncertainty

Examples:

It takes a lot of guts to admit to so many people that you've made a mistake.
 Not many people have the guts to follow their dreams, whatever it takes.
 He has that combination of skill and guts that every champion needs.

I've got the general idea of this phrase, and that's why I'm not sure if the following is natural since I don't think going bungee jumping needs the level of determination in the three above sentences. I feel that we mostly need courage when we want to try it.

I don't know if I have the guts to go bungee jumping one day.

(P.S. At this point, I feel like I can surely use it, but it took time to write such a long question, so I'll still leave it here. If this is a bad question, feel free to tell me and I'll delete it.)

"one day"  in that sentence  is quite funny.

I really appreciate how you often point out things that others don't, but could you please explain it right away next time? :D Whenever I see your comment, I know I'll need a dictionary and a comment asking to clarify.

What does "one day" mean to you as it is used in that sentence?

Like "someday".

Some day far enough in the future that there's little reason to be concerned about it now. That's why it's humorous in the context of "rising to an occasion"-- the occasion has been considerably postponed, so to speak.

@AnIELTSLearner “…one day” is odd in your sentence because it refers to a future goal, but your sentence uses the present tense.  The most common use of “one day” is at the head of sentence to introduce something that you believe will happen (“One day we will end hunger”). Using it at the end, suggests that you have confused it with “some day”.  “Some day” is less definite and has more of a sense of wishing for the thing (“We will end hunger some day”). Using “some day” would also be wrong at the end of your sentence, as you’re not stating anything that could be wished for.

@AnIELTSLearner regarding the "ONE DAY" controversy.  To be honest almost all spoken English, these days, is a little jumbled-up like that. If you literally uttered that 100% of people would understand what you mean.  For a common way to say it that is "correct"  what about "I don't know if I'll ever have the guts to go bungee jumping."

"Guts" is a slang word for "courage". Courage requires determination in a sense, like having the determination to do something dangerous despite the risk. But I suppose one could have a "casual courage", like he is so dismissive of danger that he does dangerous things without hesitating for a moment.
And of course one could have determination without being particularly courageous. Like one could be determined to stick to a diet and not eat that dessert. There's nothing particularly courageous about not eating dessert.
Short answer: Think of it as "courage", not as "determination". There might be an element of determination there and there might not.

The original source is that 'guts' is also a slang word for 'the stomach or belly', and people used to think that physical courage (i.e. not 'feeling' scared) was connected to that part of the body (a physical symptom of fear may be abdominal pain). 'Guts' was consider a rather vulgar word when I was a boy in England.

In my experience "to have the guts" refers to having the strength of character to do what is right even if doing so would be difficult.
With daredevil acts like bungee jumping it's not used as much as "have the balls". If you have a few reckless daredevil acquaintances who are trying to make you one of them, they're more likely to pressure you with "Don't you have the balls?" than "Don't you have the guts?"

Does "balls" in "have the balls" refer to, well, balls? If so, it seems inappropriate in an exam room, doesn't it?

This site is about learning English, not about doing well on exams. Many of the things daredevils say would be considered inappropriate in a "polite" essay. "Don't you have the balls?" is one of them.

And you did ask a question the other day where the example sentence involved the words "pissed" and "bro".

Wow I didn't know that saying "pissed" is inappropriate. I mean I know I shouldn't write it, but not saying it is something new.

But how is bro inappropriate? It's everywhere nowadays and just means the same as "dude", as far as  know. Does this stem from the difference between generations?

This is probably something that has changed over time. Slang references to genitalia would not have been acceptable in polite society 50 years ago, but we've become more casual. OTOH, nowadays people are more likely to object to "balls" as being a sexist term (implying that courage is a male attribute).

By the way, I don't think asking questions about if a word or phrase should be used in the exam room or not is unreasonable or violates any rules. The site is called "English language learners", so I think questions can be about English used for everyday speech or for situations where you should be more careful like classrooms or exams. You can feel free to answer or not answer a question according to your knowledge and interests, but I believe that asking these questions is not wrong. If I misunderstand the rules, please excuse me.

@AnIELTSLearner You're quite right, and I hope TimR didn't mean that questions about appropriate settings for a phrase (including exams) are off-topic here. The point should be, though, that this question hasn't asked that. It might be a great one to ask separately, though! This is a great example of the kind of "gray area" that is not highly offensive—it would be fine for chatting with friends—but not a good choice in many contexts (the office, tea with your grandmother). In the office I'd use "guts"; with some grandmothers I'd worry that even that is too "gross" and stick to Courage.

Meanwhile TimR I challenge the assertion that "balls" is more likely than "guts." It might be regional and cultural, as I grew up in the Bible Belt, where even such a slightly risqué phrase might be euphemized. I would see them as at least equally likely.

I don't agree that "guts" connotes a moral fortitude specifically. There was a 90's TV show called "Guts" that was nothing but a series of over-the-top physical challenges, with the title connoting the courage needed to best an opponent at an intimidating physical game - it wasn't a show about doing the "right thing". The term speaks to character, but I wholly disagree that someone who "has guts" is necessarily someone who does the morally correct thing.

@AnIELTSLearner Oh and yes, there are settings in which "pissed" would be too off-color or "coarse" as well. And "bro" isn't offensive, but is marked as "slang" and inappropriate for some more formal contexts.

What I object to is specific test-taking advice. What do examiners want? Is it better on a specific exam to say X or to say  Y? Do IELTS examiners want us to demonstrate that we can use a segue? That kind of thing.  And this question didn't ask about the politeness of the expression but about how it's used.

"bro" is inappropriate for even neutral contexts, IMO.  And it's not nearly as universal as TV and movies may suggest.

@AndyBonner  Let's say it's more common in secular society in that specific context. I don't expect there are many daredevils in the Bible Belt, 'cepn that fiddle player.

So how do you suggest rephrasing my question to make it easier to answer? Maybe I'll add "might" or use "an" instead of "the" to make it general? For example, is this question better: "Might "balls" be inappropriate in an exam room?" or "Is there any chance that "balls" is inappropriate in some exam room?"

Of course I know different tests require takers to do different things and I have my own judgment. When I ask about exams, I actually just ask for some kind of general cautionary reminder, not a one-size-fits-all answer.

@AnIELTSLearner  Don't ask about exams here. Ask about English.

Like I said earlier, you can choose not to answer questions you don't like. I'll still give a clear context because others are still willing to answer those questions, and actually, they often ask for it when I don't clarify. "In the exam room" is just as vague as "in more formal contexts". With all respect, I think you can be gentler with learners, in your opinions or at least in the way you express them. After all, this should be a friendly community.

A man has to have balls to use balls with no preamble.

@AnIELTSLearner I'm sure you can tell the difference between a question about a specific test and a question about an English-language-related topic that might be fodder for a test. The latter type of question is fine, the former is off-topic.
